# redirect to an image

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why can't I redirect page to a image for example:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.domain.com/images/image.gif");
```

This doesn't show me the image. Also placing conten type image/gif doesn't show the image.

Comment: What does it show you instead of the image? An error message? nothing (really? checked the HTML source?)

Comment: Are you sure there is an image where you are redirecting? Is it a script?

Comment: It was an image. Not a script. I was showing dead image place holder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me. I created an "images" folder and added the following to the Page_Load method of my Default.aspx page:

Response.Redirect("~/images/scenery.jpg");

Comment: Crap, it doest work ineed like that. I wanted to use complete URL

Answer (score 0):

try relative path, not a complete url

meaning Response.Redirect("images/image.gif");

Comment: A Response.Redirect creates a HTTP 302 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302). It shouldn't matter whether this is relative or absolute.